# Type '_Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I've been renaming some classes and packages in my aspx project and now i have this error:

> "Type '_Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the
>   same parameter types"

I have two aspx pages. In the default.aspx codebehind i see:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //error line under 'Page_Load'
    }
```

search.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="search.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

search.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    }
```

Every new ASPX page I add to my project is automaticly added to some namespace.

I've tried changing the inherits attribuut. But i couldn't find a way to fix this error and to get rid of the namespace.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

[image: My project structure]

Comment: What namespace has your _Default class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every page you add is automatically configured to namespace depending on your folder structure. I don't see enough code and structure, but are you sure, that you don't have the Page_Load defined twice? At least the error message says so. Does it behave same even when you use different class name than _Default ?

**After edits:**

Yea, there we go. You define same class (_Default) in both Default.aspx and Search.aspx ... You should rename your classes according to conventions. ie: use class "Default" in your Default.aspx and use class "Search" in your Search.aspx

Comment: But every page can still have his own Page_Load? Or am i wrong here?

Comment: Yes of course. There are two options why it doesn't work. One is because you got this Page_Load method defined in some other class, which is also "partial _Default" - all partial classes are later "glued" together. Or there could be problem with namespace, which happened during your renaming and moving operations - but this one is hard to discover without any source.

Comment: Edited my answer. You got two files defining one class (which isn't a problem itself - in some scenarios) but you are defining same method in both of them.

Comment: Thanks, I saw it when you explained me, but i still posted the source if someone else would later come here with the same question. Then he has all the info he needs.

Comment: One more question. Do you know why visual studio add a namespace to every aspx.page i add to the project?

Comment: Well.. because your classes needs namespace? Its default convention and keeps classed organized and it prevents naming collisions (what was your case actually).

Comment: Yeah i know, but there were some strange things happening i my project. I just found out i was making a Web Application Project instead of a new Website :o Yeah, I know...

Comment: I would have to see what strange things are you talking about. But this would be probably better in separate question. btw: I am also using Web App instad of Website project. Here uyu can find few questions about this difference too.

Answer (score 6):

Double click the error, temporarily rename the `Page_Load` to something else. Go down into the body of the function and type `Page_Load`. Press F12. That will get you to the place where you have second `Page_Load` method already defined. You'll probably see that it's in another *partial* `_Default` class in the *same* namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add up a specific case.

You can come across to this situation when you convert Web Site into Web Application.

When your project in form of Web Site, when you add for example `Default.aspx` into two different folders they both created without namespace with the same class name. Both declared partial and it is just fine. But when you convert into Web Application and try to build they start conflicting as they are in the same namespace, declared partial and have their own `Page_Load` methods.

One of the solutions can be giving distinct class names or encapsulating into different namespaces in accordance with the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since your class is `public partial class _Default` it's probably some naming that is causing the problem. Try to identify the other part(s) of _Default. Since it's a partial class you're able to have as many partials as you want.. Problem is probably that Page_Load is defined in one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Below follows issues I have encountered when copying files into my solution, clicking on the reported error or on "Go to Definition" mislead me to spot the cause. The hint is one line above..... !

**I'm exposing the Problem AND how I finally Resolved it**.

**Errors** when building the application:

- Error    1    Type 'Solution1.Web.yourABC' already defines a member
  called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types
  C:\\trunk\Solution1.Web\yourABC.aspx.cs    12    24
  Solution1.Web
- Error    2    Type 'Solution1.Web.yourABC' already defines a member
  called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types
  C:\\trunk\Solution1.Web\GuideABT.aspx.cs    12    24
  Solution1.Web

How the problem arose:
I copy/pasted a file .aspx in the same solution to make a new file.
C#: Error like below started to appear; worst other misleading errors started to impact the application at runtime:

** Be aware that error 1 IS NOT an error it is CORRECT, as it is the source code*

```
Error    1    Type 'Solution1.Web.yourABC' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types    C:\<folderpath>\trunk\Solution1.Web\yourABC.aspx.cs    12    24    Solution1.Web 

Error    2    Type 'Solution1.Web.yourABC' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types    C:\<folderpath>\trunk\Solution1.Web\GuideABT.aspx.cs    12    24    Solution1.Web
```

Both classes "Page_Load" are empty, normally they are generated automatically by the Visual Studio Engine

**Solution**:
Change the .cs file of the newly create/pasted aspx page to reflect the page name after the Class "name". In this case "GuideABT.aspx" is the new pasted & renamed aspx file:

Correction on Error 1: NO CORRECTION NEEDED as it is the copied from file. MAKE SURE THAT the name of the file and the name of the class reference ARE the same in the .cs files:

*File name yourABC.aspx, check the .cs extension files:*

```
namespace Solution1.Web
{
    public partial class yourABC : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Correction on Error 2: MODIFY the pasted file. Correct the CLASS NAME to reflect the name of the .aspx file.

File name GuideABT.aspx, check the .cs extension files:
ORIGINAL code in .cs

```
namespace Solution1.Web
{
    public partial class *yourABC* : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

CORRECTED this code in .cs TO

```
namespace Solution1.Web
{
    public partial class **GuideABT** : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Issue RESOLVED.

Cheers.